# Number of different vectors.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinations

Let's say that I have a vector with 6 elements. I put two wedges in the vector, i.e., at position 2 and position 6, for instance. And when I say put a wedge, it means... for every time you traverse (Forwards or backwards, only two positions) that position all the positions will be updated with that value. At the risk of sounding insane, let me explain this with an example:

> x 2 x x x x 6

How many different ways would there be to so that the vector gets a different value? In this case, there would be 4:

** 2 2 2 2 2 6
** 2 2 2 2 6 6
** 2 2 2 6 6 6
** 2 2 6 6 6 6

How do I generalize this for a vector with say 1000 elements, and more than half the number of wedges?

Comment: What do you mean by 'traverse'? and what do you mean by 'all the positions'? I'm finding it hard to understand what you are describing. Also, what sort of answer are you looking for? Are you aiming for an algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Cheers!

Comment: @Joao: Thank you for your wise words. I read the faq, and the typeset Mathematics page, too. It was important. Thank you.

Comment: @JessicaB: Yes, I am looking for an algorithm. Or, a mathematical relation to describe the same. When I say "traverse", what I mean is you start from the first position, and can walk and end your traversal randomly. You will only have two directions to move. (Forwards, and backwards, obviously!) Let's say you start from position 1, there's no wedge, go to position 2, find a wedge, replace 1 with 2, then traverse till the end where the wedge on the sixth position will take over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each pair of consecutive wedges take different values, there must be exactly one change in value somewhere between any two wedges. You can make the change where you want, by walking to the later wedge, then walking back as far as you want before continuing to the next.

Comment: Ha! This makes sense. Guess, I wasn't looking at the problem very carefully. Thanks for making me see a simple fact, JessicaB. That helped.